# AspectJ - Compile time Weaving With xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I am trying to create a java aspectj (using @Aspectj annotation) framework which will silently capture data and publish it to another system when it is integrated with Java service components ( JBOSS , Tomcat). For example, The framework will support capturing Request and response data of the service APIs and data loaded from Database by the service for the API call ( there are more kind of data will be captured other than example that i have provided) .

1. Service component owner will provide a xml which will map the domain object methods to specific aspect method for capturing data.  ( Service owner can decide certain DB data is not needed to be captured.)
2. For the component services to use this capability, they will compile the service component with the jar that provide using aspectj-maven-plugin. ( I would like to go with compile time weaving rather than load time weaving as it may influence the runtime performance of the services ).   What I am trying to achieve is that aspectj compilation should consider the xml and map the pointcut and advice according to xml configuration to the aspect class methods.

   With extensive browsing on this topic, i see that it is possible with spring xml configuration.  For the spring xml configuration, every domain object ( for which advice code needs to be injected) has to be either a bean or annotated with @configurable.  It would be impossible to modify all service domain objects to be annotated with @configurable.  [Added Point ] Spring XML ( Spring AOP) will not work for me as it is Load time weaving. so this point is not valid.

so the question is that "Is it possible to enable compile time weaving of AspectJ(annotation) using xml configuration ( point cuts and advice map to aspect methods) ?"

Comment: The question is unclear. Too much prose, no code. Plus, you are mixing up a few topice here: AspectJ CTW does not need any XML configuration, especially no Spring configurartion. AspectJ-related XML is used for LTW in the form of *aop.xml*, but you want to avoid LTW. Spring AOP, OTOH, is a proxy-based "AOP lite" framework which used dynamic proxies generated during runti9me and only works for Spring components, as you said. So which one do you want to use? My educated guess would be plain AspectJ CTW because you mentioned *aspectj-maven-plugin*. That one does not need any XML config, as I said

Comment: As i have mentioned in the question, i want to avoid LTW.  So I am right now using plain AspectJ CTW using aspectj-maven-plugin.   I am declaring the point cut and advice in my aspect classes using AspectJ annotation style.  So I am referring the domain object method classes in my aspectj pointcut signature.  I want to avoid it by CTW possible with xml configuration.   What i am asking is possible If ajc compiler understands the pointcuts and advices of the aspect from the xml configuration rather than aspect classes annotation. But i think, such feature is not available.

Comment: When i was asking this question, i was in the wrong assumption that Spring AOP ( with xml ) is compile time and not run time.  i have edited the question about that part.

Comment: As I said before: Show the code! Ideally provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). For the time being the question is too esoteric and abstract, I will vote to close it until you provide more information because this way it just stimulates unspecific discussion. Sorry about that, but it is true.